# Linux remove whitespace first line

Tags: linux, sed

i have the file virt.txt contains:

```
0302        000000       23071SOCIETY              117
0602        000000000000000001 PAYMENT              BANK
```

I want to remove 3 whitespaces from 6th to 8th column to the first line only.

I do:

```
 sed '1s/[[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]//6' virt.txt
```

it'KO
please help

Answer (score 2):

Your regex would consume all the available blanks from a sequence of three or more (in a quite inefficient way) and replace the sixth occurrence of *that*. Because your first input line does not contain six or more separate stretches of three or more whitespace characters, it actually did nothing.  But you can in fact use `sed` to do exactly what you say you want:

```sh
sed '1s/^\(.....\)   /\1/' virt.txt
```

(or for convenience, if you have `sed -E` or the variant `sed -r` which works on some platforms, but neither of these is standard):

```sh
sed -E '1s/^(.{5}) {3}/\1/' virt.txt  # -E is not portable
```

The parentheses capture the first five characters into a back reference, and we then use the first back reference `\1` as the replacement string, effectively replacing only the text which matched outside the parentheses.

If your `sed` supports the `-i` option, you can use that to modify the file directly; but this is also not standard, so the most portable solution is to write the result to a new file, then move it back on top of the original file if you want to replace it.

`sed` is convenient if you are familiar with it, but as you are clearly not, perhaps a better approach would be to use a different language, ideally one which is not write-only for many users, like `sed`.

If you know the three characters will always be spaces, just do a static replacement.

```sh
awk 'NR==1 { $0 = substr($0, 1, 5) substr($0, 9) } 1' virt.txt
```

On the first line (`NR` is the current input line number) replace the input line `$0` with a catenation of the substrings on both sides of the part you want to cut.

For a simple replacement like that, you can also use basic Unix text manipulation utilities, though it's rather inefficient and inelegant:

```sh
head -n 1 virt.txt | cut -c1-5,9- >newfile.txt
tail -n +2 virt.txt >>newfile.txt
```

If you need to check that the three characters are spaces, the Awk script only needs a minor tweak.

```sh
awk 'NR==1 && /^.{5} {3}/ { $0 = substr($0, 1, 5) substr($0, 9) } 1' virt.txt
```

You should vaguely recognize the regex from above. Awk is less succinct, but as a consequence also quite a lot more readable, than `sed`.